# Coloured footnotes split across multiple pages

Tags: color, footnotes

I am typesetting a book with long footnotes, and some phrases or words in footnotes are colored. I ran into a problem for which I have an MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3]\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}}
\lipsum[4-20]
\end{document}
```

Whats wrong here? The textcolor work fine for the footnote text on the first page, but the continued footnote on the second page is not affected?

I am using XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX).

**Edited at 10:20 PM on Friday, 9 May, 2014 (GMT):**

Thanks for the responses, using bigfoot helped. One minor thing which I think does not need a new question. Redefining `\thefootnote` seems to have no effect with `bigfoot`. How to make the following work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
% The line below has no effect
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{red}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3]\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}}
\lipsum[4-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an explanation but adding `\usepackage{bigfoot}` might/should help

Comment: the problem is that "original" tex had no control over colour; there were colour packages before the present `color`/``xcolor` packages, but none of them aspired to offer a general solution.  the latex packages deal with most things, but not footnotes splitting under the direct influence of something other than the page maker.

Answer (score 16):

### pdfTeX

This is a typical case, where multiple colorstacks are needed, one for the main text and one for footnotes. This is provided by [pdfTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf) and package `pdfcolfoot` 
adds support for an additional color stack for foonotes (basic footnotes of LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcolfoot}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3]\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}}
\lipsum[4-20]
\end{document}
```

### LuaTeX

LuaTeX has a new concept: attributes. Package [`luacolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacolor) implements color via an attribute:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3]\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-5]}}
\lipsum[4-20]
\end{document}
```

### Package `bigfoot`

It's a great package with many features, from its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/bigfoot.pdf):

> You can use color in footnotes. If a footnote gets broken across
>   pages, the color at the point of the break will get resumed on the
>   next page. Actually, the whole color stack will get reinstated.

However, if I remember correctly, there might be problems with `hyperref`s footnote linking.

### Others

Out of luck.

Comment: As @cgneider mentioned, one of `bigfoot`'s improvements over regular footnoting is that it is aware of the colour stack and breaks/reinstates it when footnotes are broken across pages.  Thus, you could use it for XeTeX-produced documents (or, of course, pdfTeX and LuaTeX ones).  (Good to learn of `pdfcolfoot` and `luacolor`, though!)

Comment: @jon: However it does not work well with `hyperref`. But I can add it to the list.

Comment: @jon: Try it. I do not remember the details.

Comment: The footnotemark --> footnote link is disabled under all engines. (Relying on your example files, but modified for use with `bigfoot` and without `pdfcolfoot` and with/without `luacolor`.)  I don't have time to perform more extensive tests right now, unfortunately.